# Any solutions about slow website loading? (VueJS and PHP API with MySQL DB)

Tags: php, mysql, vue.js, redbean, http-status-code-504

I know that my question could be unclear, but let me firstly explain the issue to give me your advice.

I've built a website using VueJS linked it with PHP API (Redbean ORM) with MySQL DB engine hosted with GoDaddy Economy Shared plan and everything works fine as well.

For the first months of production, it works fine with its data and the client and his visits. But recently, the website is getting slow in responding the requests to server and also for the first load. Sometimes works good but suddenly stops loading and getting (504 Gateway Time-out) HTTP response. Even with some browsers works and some other does not, also with some mobile platforms like iPhone getting slow loading. As you know, VueJS uses SPA to make website super faster than traditional loading navigation.

It's clear that maybe the shared hosting plan is the main reason and we should upgrade to higher business plans to solve it, but I preferred to ask the community here if anyone has any idea to solve this issue.

The website object is online store and gallery for cosmetics and makeups, no payment APIs integrated.

Any ideas may I use to improve stability and responding? Thank you.

Comment: There is no way for us to find out why the application on your server is slow. Did you trace which part of it is responsible for being so slow?

Comment: I traced all website and the problem is not for some parts or sections. The idea is stop responding the server requests even for simplest handled data. The problem is with the request, not with its data coming from (as i detected).

Comment: @nael_d You may find out how 'shared' your website is with this website.  myip.ms and enter your site name for a report including (scroll down)  how many sites are using the same shared IP address.  If you post the first two pages of this response we can see the situation you are finding might be tolerable.  I suspect godaddy.com could provide a 'dedicated' ip address for you at a reasonable price.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.